# Unity project build in Xcode, crash randomly, i don't know why... help please

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, unity-game-engine, crash

Xcode version is 6.1
Unity version is 4.54f1 and NGUI 2.6.1

I'm sure that there is no error logged on console when running in the **UnityEngine**, but when running on **iPhone**, it crashes about once an hour.
I tried to use **dSYM** to trace the error, but all I saw is memory address and I don't understand.

1. Is there any options in unity or Xcode that can help me to avoid crashes like this?

   Here are my settings:

   script call optimization is `"Slow and Safe"`
    Optimization Level is `"None[-O0]"`
2. What kind of mistake can cause crashes like this, memory mistakes?
3. Way to trace the error line in my code.

   Thread 0 Crashed:

   ```
   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f551fc __pthread_kill + 8
   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37fbea2e pthread_kill + 54
   2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37f05ff8 abort + 72
   3   pp                              0x01e2489c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 312
   4   pp                              0x01e1420c mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 256
   5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x37fb9060 _sigtramp + 40
   6   pp                              0x01f10e34 g_logv + 160
   7   pp                              0x01f10e5c g_log + 28
   8   pp                              0x01e18d64 get_numerous_trampoline + 368
   9   pp                              0x01e1c874 mono_aot_create_specific_trampoline + 468
   10  pp                              0x01e26aa4 mono_create_specific_trampoline + 72
   11  pp                              0x01e26f5c mono_create_jit_trampoline_in_domain + 328
   12  pp                              0x01e27088 mono_create_jit_trampoline + 20
   13  pp                              0x01e14604 mono_resolve_patch_target + 504
   14  pp                              0x01e1ddf0 mono_aot_plt_resolve + 452
   15  pp                              0x01e26040 mono_aot_plt_trampoline + 32
   16  pp                              0x016cbae8 generic_trampoline_6 + 120
   17  pp                              0x0162295c m_wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (mscorlib.dll.s:354297)
   18  pp                              0x01e13ab0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2152
   19  pp                              0x01eb5d60 mono_runtime_invoke + 132
   20  pp                              0x01a01148 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethod*, MonoObject*, MonoException**) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:933)
   21  pp                              0x01a01284 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethod*, MonoObject*) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:973)
   22  pp                              0x01a10a34 Scripting::SendScriptingMessage(Unity::GameObject&, char const*, MonoObject*) (Scripting.cpp:147)
   23  pp                              0x01a10b18 Scripting::SendScriptingMessage(Unity::GameObject&, std::string const&, MonoObject*, int) (Scripting.cpp:186)
   24  pp                              0x01c26c6c GameObject_CUSTOM_SendMessage(ReadOnlyScriptingObjectOfType<Unity::GameObject>, ICallString, MonoObject*, int) (UnityEngineGameObject.cpp:343)
   25  pp                              0x01168a54 m_wrapper_managed_to_native_UnityEngine_GameObject_SendMessage_string_object_UnityEngine_SendMessageOptions (UnityEngine.dll.s:51208)
   26  pp                              0x002503f4 m_UIEventListener_OnClick (Assembly-CSharp.dll.s:20588)
   27  pp                              0x0162295c m_wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (mscorlib.dll.s:354297)
   28  pp                              0x01e13ab0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2152
   29  pp                              0x01eb5d60 mono_runtime_invoke + 132
   30  pp                              0x01a01148 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethod*, MonoObject*, MonoException**) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:933)
   31  pp                              0x01a01284 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethod*, MonoObject*) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:973)
   32  pp                              0x01a10a34 Scripting::SendScriptingMessage(Unity::GameObject&, char const*, MonoObject*) 
   (Scripting.cpp:147)
   33  pp                              0x01a10b18 Scripting::SendScriptingMessage(Unity::GameObject&, std::string const&, MonoObject*, int) (Scripting.cpp:186)
   34  pp                              0x01c26c6c GameObject_CUSTOM_SendMessage(ReadOnlyScriptingObjectOfType<Unity::GameObject>, ICallString, MonoObject*, int) (UnityEngineGameObject.cpp:343)
   35  pp                              0x01168a54 m_wrapper_managed_to_native_UnityEngine_GameObject_SendMessage_string_object_UnityEngine_SendMessageOptions (UnityEngine.dll.s:51208)
   36  pp                              0x0025e990 m_UICamera_ProcessTouch_bool_bool (Assembly-CSharp.dll.s:26704)
   37  pp                              0x0025d75c m_UICamera_ProcessTouches (Assembly-CSharp.dll.s:26229)
   38  pp                              0x0025c594 m_UICamera_Update (Assembly-CSharp.dll.s:25808)
   39  pp                              0x0162295c m_wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (mscorlib.dll.s:354297)
   40  pp                              0x01e13ab0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2152
   41  pp                              0x01eb5d60 mono_runtime_invoke + 132
   42  pp                              0x01961f8c scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethod*, MonoObject*, ScriptingArguments&, MonoException**) (ScriptingBackendApi_Mono.cpp:199)
   43  pp                              0x01a0cb30 ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke(MonoException**) (ScriptingInvocationNoArgs.cpp:95)
   44  pp                              0x01a0caec ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke() (ScriptingInvocationNoArgs.cpp:79)
   45  pp                              0x01a003a8 MonoBehaviour::CallUpdateMethod(int) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:612)
   46  pp                              0x01a003c0 MonoBehaviour::Update() (MonoBehaviour.cpp:617)
   47  pp                              0x0194b884 void BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>() (Behaviour.cpp:156)
   48  pp                              0x0194bc50 BehaviourManager::Update() (Behaviour.cpp:172)
   49  pp                              0x019d2be4 PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*) (Player.cpp:1895)
   50  pp                              0x017cda74 UnityPlayerLoop (LibEntryPoint.mm:239)
   51  pp                              0x017925bc -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaint] (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:55)
   52  pp                              0x017923b0 -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:34)
   53  QuartzCore                      0x2facb9ca CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 94
   54  QuartzCore                      0x2facb774 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 340
   55  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x326c176a IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 102
   56  IOKit                           0x2e363a72 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 246
   57  CoreFoundation                  0x2d641e1e __CFMachPortPerform + 134
   58  CoreFoundation                  0x2d64c9dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
   59  CoreFoundation                  0x2d64c976 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
   60  CoreFoundation                  0x2d64b14a __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
   61  CoreFoundation                  0x2d5b5c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
   62  CoreFoundation                  0x2d5b5a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
   63  GraphicsServices                0x322a527e GSEventRunModal + 134
   64  UIKit                           0x2fe59044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
   65  pp                              0x000cde78 main (main.mm:28)
   66  pp                              0x000cdd54 start + 36
   ```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace or crash log?

Comment: @trojanfoe hi, I posted the crash log below.

Comment: OK now you have to symbolicate that crash log so you can see where in the source the crash originated.  Then update the question with the symbolicated version.

Comment: Yup, read up on symbolicating crash logs. As is this log does not give any hints whatsoever.

Comment: here are my symbolicated crash logs. any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 of your trace, **mono_handle_native_sigsegv** indicates you are trying to access a NULL object.

If you don't see this in the editor, but you do on a device, keep in mind that timing will be different on different devices. It's possible that due to timing differences, the line that is causing the problem is called before the object is nullified in the editor, but after on the device.

It looks like its happening somewhere you are responding to an OnClick message.

Comment: thanks, but unity3d can catch NullReferenceError, it just logout the error but it won't crash on device, i'm sure it's working.

Comment: A null reference will crash your device.  It won't crash in the editor (but will likely abruptly end the current frame), but will on the device.